# IIS 7 and SPN Issues

Tags: active-directory, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

Our web server is on a different box than our SQL server.  When I first set up the website, I could access it, but it wasn't passing the authenticated user credentials to our SQL server (as expected).

I did the `SETSPN -A` configuration to add the SPN to our domain for the new website on the webserver (as we always do), and now the website is challenging for user id and password, but won't accept the credentials (3 times, then no access 401).

The website is configured for `Identity Impersonation` and `windows authentication`, just like the other 8 websites on the same server with the same configuration, that all work.

This only occurs on NEW websites, and usually, we have to reboot the server to fix it.

Any suggestions to get this to work with out a reboot?

Comment: Tried an `IISreset`?

Comment: NTLM authentication in IIS, standard application pool using ApplicationPoolIdentity, and single server, no farm. As far as IIS Reset, I'd like to reitterate: This is a production server! The point is, I'd like to be able to set up a new website on it, without having to take down all of the other existing websites. But so far, since we run SETSPN, we haven't been able to do this.  And no, IISRESET /RESTART does not work.

Comment: OK I still am not clear on what you mean. Does your application pool run as a domain account or not? Please look in the identity tab for details. When you say NTLM authenticationdo you mean that is the only provider configured in settings for Windows Integrated authentication? You dont have negotiate as a provider?

Comment: I would look at trusting the computer for delegation in Active Directory.

Comment: +1 to Will. yes this would be one of the required steps if the app pool identity is network service. Else you'd configure the SPN on the service account used for the app pool and also configure this service account to be trusted for delegation as applicable. Either unconstrained or constrained to the SQL related SPN's specifically. But hard to suggest an answer until BlueProdigy is clear about exactly what is his configuration. I.e. account used for app pool, kernel mode auth usage etc.

Comment: Please read the issue above, this is not the first website set up on this computer ("just like the other 8 websites on the same server with the same configuration, that all work").  Delegation is set in AD on the server.  "ApplicationPoolIdentity" is the account the application pools run on (which I explained in my comment), and the authentication providers are:  Negotiate, then NTLM.